# Error Key- value coding-compliant for the key view although reinstall app

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

This error occurs on my real device. Although I delete app & data, reinstall app, reset all setting & content on my iPhone, it still error. But it run normally on simulator. Anyone have same problems please help me!

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details starting with the actual and complete error message.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a help site for programming. Is your question about programming? We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research.

Comment: This may be wrong IBOutlet with wrong or rubbish values. Check your storyboard's connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone is case-sensitive , the simulator is not.
So there's probably a typo on the key , but this error occurs only when running on the real device.

You have to write the correct name of the key to solve the issue.